# Trying to clear a array when all values are inserted on other array

Tags: arrays, lua, fivem

So im trying to clear the array `NewPassagers` when all values inside passed to `OnBusPassagers`.
Its for a FiveM script btw!

```
 if GetVehicleNumberOfPassengers(veh) > 1 then
              for i = 1, #NewPassagers, 1 do
                  table.insert(OnBusPassagers, NewPassagers)
              end
              NewPassagers = nil
          end
```

Comment: What are you expecting? Currently you aren't "clearing" the array, you're setting it to `nil`. If other parts of your code expect an empty "array" (table) instead of `nil`, set it to `{}` instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe lets do a while, table.insert() and table.remove() do the job...

```
local tab1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
local tab2 = {}

while #tab1 ~= 0 do
-- Reverse order
--  table.insert(tab2, table.remove(tab1))
-- Same order
  table.insert(tab2, table.remove(tab1, 1))
end

return tab2
```

...table.remove({}[, pos]) removes last key/value by default without pos and returning that value for table.insert().

Comment: soo its not possible to make table.remove on the first key/ value?

Comment: It is possible, but the whole key/value pairs have to be shifted in the source table tab1 at every table.remove(tab1, 1).